# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "stripe_ios"

Tags: ios, flutter, deployment

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "stripe_ios":
In Podfile:
stripe_ios (from `.symlinks/plugins/stripe_ios/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `stripe_ios (from` .symlinks/plugins/stripe_ios/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum
deployment target.

Comment: Just as it said, upgrade your deployment target version. Project -> Target -> Minimum Deployments

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering with CocoaPods is indicating that the stripe_ios pod requires a higher minimum iOS deployment target than what is currently set in your project.
Check Stripe iOS SDK Requirements and update Your Project's Deployment Target. Then, update CocoaPods, and clean and rebuild your app. Then it will be fine.